# CHECK: Let $M$ be the set of all integer linear combinations of $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$. Prove that $M$ is closed under addition and multiplication

Tags: number-theory

Let $M$ be the set of all integer linear combinations of $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$. Prove that

1. $M$ is closed under addition: $u,v \in M$ implies $u+v \in M$
2. $M$ is closed under multiplication by any $k \in \mathbb{Z}$: $u \in
       M$ implies $k \cdot u \in M$

$\textbf{Proof of (i):}$ We want to show that $u+v \in M$, for some $u,v \in M$. So let $ay_1+bz_1=u \in M$ and $ay_2+bz_2=v\in M$, where $y_1,y_2,z_1,z_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then $$u+v=ay_1+bz_1+ay_2+bz_2=a(y_1+y_2)+b(z_1+z_2)$$ 
Since $y_1+y_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$ and$z_1+z_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $u+v$ is an integer linear combination of $a,b$. Hence $u+v \in M$.

$\textbf{Proof of (ii):}$ We want to show that $u \cdot v \in M$, for some $u,v \in M$. So let $ay_1+bz_1=u \in M$ and $ay_2+bz_2=v\in M$, where $y_1,y_2,z_1,z_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
u\cdot v & =(ay_1+bz_1)\cdot (ay_2+bz_2) \\
& =ay_1ay_2+ay_1bz_2+bz_1ay_2+bz_1bz_2 \\
& =a^2y_1y_2+ab(y_1z_2+y_2z_1)+b^2z_1z_2\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
Since $y_1y_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$, $y_1z_2+y_2z_1 \in \mathbb{Z}$, and $z_1z_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $u \cdot v$ is an integer linear combination of $a,b$. Hence $u\cdot v \in M$.

Comment: I think you no longer need someone checking your proofs. They are fine - mostly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of your proof works well. In the second part you need to prove that an integral multiple of any element of $M$ is again there, this is obvious as integral  multiple of a $ax+by$ is again of the same form. You don't need to prove that the product of two elements of $M$ again belongs to $M$.